# Postfix gives error in maillog: maps_find: smtp_generic_maps: log: not found

Tags: centos, email, postfix, smtp

I have changed the default FROM address of Postfix, from root@example.com to log@example.com

I can send the e-mails fine, but when I check the maillog file I then see some "**not found**" errors.

**/etc/maillog:**

```
Feb 24 11:52:28 webserver postfix/smtp[9789]: maps_find: smtp_generic_maps: log@example.com: not found
Feb 24 11:52:28 webserver postfix/smtp[9789]: maps_find: smtp_generic_maps: log: not found
Feb 24 11:52:28 webserver postfix/smtp[9789]: maps_find: smtp_generic_maps: @example.com: not found
Feb 24 11:52:28 webserver postfix/smtp[9789]: mail_addr_find: log@example.com -> (not found)
Feb 24 11:52:28 webserver postfix/smtp[9789]: mail_addr_map: log@example.com -> (not found)
Feb 24 11:52:28 webserver postfix/smtp[9789]: smtp_map11_external: log@example.com not found
Feb 24 11:52:28 webserver postfix/smtp[9789]: > smtp-relay.gmail.com[74.125.129.28]:587: RCPT TO:<log@example.com>
Feb 24 11:52:28 webserver postfix/smtp[9789]: > smtp-relay.gmail.com[74.125.129.28]:587: DATA
Feb 24 11:52:28 webserver postfix/smtp[9789]: smtp_stream_setup: maxtime=300 enable_deadline=0
Feb 24 11:52:28 webserver postfix/smtp[9789]: < smtp-relay.gmail.com[74.125.129.28]:587: 250 2.1.0 OK f70sm1283942ita.7 - gsm
tp
Feb 24 11:52:28 webserver postfix/smtp[9789]: smtp_stream_setup: maxtime=300 enable_deadline=0
Feb 24 11:52:28 webserver postfix/smtp[9789]: < smtp-relay.gmail.com[74.125.129.28]:587: 250 2.1.5 OK f70sm1283942ita.7 - gsm
tp
Feb 24 11:52:28 webserver postfix/smtp[9789]: smtp_stream_setup: maxtime=120 enable_deadline=0
Feb 24 11:52:28 webserver postfix/smtp[9789]: < smtp-relay.gmail.com[74.125.129.28]:587: 354  Go ahead f70sm1283942ita.7 - gs
mtp
Feb 24 11:52:28 webserver postfix/smtp[9789]: smtp_stream_setup: maxtime=180 enable_deadline=0
Feb 24 11:52:28 webserver postfix/smtp[9789]: maps_find: smtp_generic_maps: log@example.com: not found
Feb 24 11:52:28 webserver postfix/smtp[9789]: maps_find: smtp_generic_maps: log: not found
Feb 24 11:52:28 webserver postfix/smtp[9789]: maps_find: smtp_generic_maps: @example.com: not found
Feb 24 11:52:28 webserver postfix/smtp[9789]: mail_addr_find: log@example.com -> (not found)
Feb 24 11:52:28 webserver postfix/smtp[9789]: mail_addr_map: log@example.com -> (not found)
Feb 24 11:52:28 webserver postfix/smtp[9789]: smtp_map11_external: log@example.com not found
Feb 24 11:52:28 webserver postfix/smtp[9789]: maps_find: smtp_generic_maps: hash:/etc/postfix/generic(0,lock|fold_fix): root 
= log@example.com
Feb 24 11:52:28 webserver postfix/smtp[9789]: mail_addr_find: root -> log@example.com
Feb 24 11:52:28 webserver postfix/smtp[9789]: rewrite_clnt: cached: local: log@example.com -> log@example.com
Feb 24 11:52:28 webserver postfix/smtp[9789]: mail_addr_map: root -> 0: log@example.com
Feb 24 11:52:28 webserver postfix/smtp[9789]: smtp_map11_external: root -> log@example.com
Feb 24 11:52:28 webserver postfix/smtp[9789]: > smtp-relay.gmail.com[74.125.129.28]:587: .
Feb 24 11:52:28 webserver postfix/smtp[9789]: > smtp-relay.gmail.com[74.125.129.28]:587: QUIT
Feb 24 11:52:28 webserver postfix/smtp[9789]: smtp_stream_setup: maxtime=600 enable_deadline=0
Feb 24 11:52:28 webserver postfix/smtp[9789]: < smtp-relay.gmail.com[74.125.129.28]:587: 250 2.0.0 OK 1519469548 f70sm1283942
ita.7 - gsmtp
Feb 24 11:52:28 webserver postfix/smtp[9789]: 078471910084: to=<log@example.com>, relay=smtp-relay.gmail.com[74.125.129.28]:
587, delay=0.2, delays=0.02/0.02/0.12/0.04, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK 1519469548 f70sm1283942ita.7 - gsmtp)
Feb 24 11:52:28 webserver postfix/smtp[9789]: name_mask: resource
Feb 24 11:52:28 webserver postfix/smtp[9789]: name_mask: software
Feb 24 11:52:28 webserver postfix/smtp[9789]: disposing SASL state information
Feb 24 11:52:28 webserver postfix/qmgr[6455]: 078471910084: removed
```

**/etc/postfix/main.cf**

```
smtp_generic_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/generic
```

**/etc/postfix/generic**

```
root log@example.com
```

So everything works, but still these errors. Why does the maillog first say "not found" and then a few lines further it says it is found?

Comment: anyone some suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Seems that the `maps_find` lines are debugging informations from the mapping process setted into your `/etc/postfix/generic`. Your mapping process terminates with

```
maps_find: smtp_generic_maps: hash:/etc/postfix/generic(0,lock|fold_fix): root
```

which says this email will be sent to root

checkout the `debug_peer_list` and `debug_peer_level` into your `main.cf` for disabling this option (I personally commented it out and solved my logs from being too verbose). You can find more documentation [here](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html) about these options